# SqlParameter and c#

Tags: c#, sql

Hi all please can someone help me out with this. I have spend nearly 2 days trying to figure this one out.

I have a this parameter query in c#

```
UPDATE [User] 
SET LoginName = '@LoginName', Name = '@Name',
    Surname = '@Surname', Telphone = '@Telphone', 
    Cellphone = '@Cellphone', Fax = '@Fax', Email = '@Email', 
    Password = '@Password', PasswordCreationDate = @PasswordCreationDate, 
    IsActive = @IsActive, ManagerID = @ManagerID, 
    SuperVisorID = @SuperVisorID, TeamLeaderID = @TeamLeaderID, 
    PermissionID = @PermissionID 
WHERE UserID = @UserID
```

I have this assign the value '' to the `@Telephone` parameter but it fails so I opened up SQL Server Profiler and I saw it gave me this

```
USE Collector
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [User] SET LoginName=''@LoginName'', Name=''@Name'', Surname=''@Surname'', 
Telphone=''@Telphone'',
 Cellphone=''@Cellphone'', Fax=''@Fax'', 
Email=''@Email'', Password=''@Password'', PasswordCreationDate = @PasswordCreationDate, 
IsActive = @IsActive, ManagerID = @ManagerID, SuperVisorID = @SuperVisorID, 
TeamLeaderID = @TeamLeaderID, PermissionID = @PermissionID WHERE UserID = @UserID',
N'@UserID int,@LoginName nvarchar(6),@Name nvarchar(9),@Surname nvarchar(8),
@Telphone nvarchar(4000)
,@Cellphone nvarchar(4),@Fax nvarchar(3),@Email nvarchar(3),
@Password nvarchar(32),@PasswordCreationDate datetime,@IsActive bit,@ManagerID int,
@SuperVisorID int,@TeamLeaderID int,@PermissionID int',@UserID=29,@LoginName=N'daniel',
@Name=N'Daniel123',@Surname=N'asdfasdf',
@Telphone=DEFAULT,
@Cellphone=N'3453',@Fax=N'345',
@Email=N'adf',@Password=N'5F4DCC3B5AA765D61D8327DEB882CF99',
@PasswordCreationDate='2015-04-03 21:55:57',@IsActive=1,@ManagerID=7,@SuperVisorID=7,
@TeamLeaderID=7,@PermissionID=1
```

No looking at this query I see that it has placed the word DEFAULT in there even thought I had specifically assigned '' so it comes back with a warning.

> The parameterized query '(@UserID int,@LoginName nvarchar(6), @Name nvarchar(9),@Surname n' expects the parameter '@Telphone', which was not supplied.

But I did assign a '' to it `new SqlParameter("@Telphone", "''");`

What am I missing? I need another set of eyes please help.

table def:

```
USE [Collector]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User]    Script Date: 2015/04/11 08:19:09 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [UserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LoginName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Telphone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Cellphone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Fax] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordCreationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_User_IsActive]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [ManagerID] [int] NULL,
    [SuperVisorID] [int] NULL,
    [TeamLeaderID] [int] NULL,
    [PermissionID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Thanks for all the eyes. I manage to trace the issue

the culprit.. I had to modify the reflection part to check if it is a string and not use the default value that would be null.

```
public static object GetDefaultValue(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

        Expression<Func<object>> e = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(
            Expression.Convert(
            Expression.Default(type), typeof(object)
            )
        );

        // Compile and return the value.
        return e.Compile()();
    }
```

Comment: Is the parameter supposed to be spelled `@Telephone`, not `@Telphone`?

Comment: Yes the spelling should read Telphone

Comment: Ok, make sure you don't have any place in the code where you are spelling it `@Telephone`.  For example, in your paragraph above: "I have this assign the value '' to the @Telephone parameter but it fails so I opened up Sql profiler and I saw it gave me this", you spell it as `@Telephone`.

Comment: 100% sure it is everywhere the same

Comment: Ok.  How about trying to set an actual telephone number, instead of passing `''`.  Does that change anything?

Comment: Then it works. What the codes does is use reflections, the class was made with entity framework so it matches exactly, The code then retrieves the record and place this in the object, and it uses this object with reflections to create a list of sqlparameters that mathes the column name etc.

Comment: What's the data definition of the column Telphone in the destination table?

Comment: @user3731074: SQL Server doesn't have a `string` data type. Do you mean `varchar` or `nvarchar`?

Comment: I meant in the database table.  Probably a varchar?  Does it allow Nulls?

Comment: I have updated with a create script.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use single quotes with parameters. Just use them like;

```
Telphone = @Telphone
```

With single quote, sql sees it as a [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal), not a parameter.

Comment: Msg 8178, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
The parameterized query '(@UserID int,@LoginName nvarchar(4),@Name nvarchar(9),@Surname n' expects the parameter '@Telphone', which was not supplied.

Comment: @user3731074 Have you ever add those parameters and their values to your command? Can you show your relevant C# code as well?

Comment: I have added it this way. var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            var cmd = new SqlCommand { CommandText = sqlUpdate, Connection = con };
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlPar.ToArray());

Comment: @user3731074 Are you sure this parameters are belongs on `sqlPar`? And update your question with relevant and complete code as well.

Comment: HI soner can i email this code to you so that you can see. as its to big still bit messy but to big to put on here

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have apostrophes around parameters, that makes them literal string values instead of parameters. It would for example save `'@LoginName'` in the table instead of `'daniel'.`The query should be:

```
UPDATE [User] SET LoginName=@LoginName, Name=@Name,
Surname=@Surname, Telphone=@Telphone, 
Cellphone=@Cellphone, Fax=@Fax, Email=@Email, 
Password=@Password, PasswordCreationDate = @PasswordCreationDate, 
IsActive = @IsActive, ManagerID = @ManagerID, 
SuperVisorID = @SuperVisorID, TeamLeaderID = @TeamLeaderID, 
PermissionID = @PermissionID WHERE UserID = @UserID
```

Regarding the `@Telphone` parameter, it seems that you actually didn't add it to the command before executing it. Check the spelling, and check where and how you add it to the command.

Comment: Thanks Guffy now it explains why I have that in the table. :)

Comment: I have done it this way, var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            var cmd = new SqlCommand { CommandText = sqlUpdate, Connection = con };
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlPar.ToArray());

Comment: @user3731074: Then the parameter isn't in the `sqlPar` collection. How do you create that?

Comment: All 15 paramers is present, I have run it in  debug mode and looked at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new SqlParameter("@Telphone", DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: Hi there, I have done it that way, it works, but since I have not figured out how to know if the column in the db supports null, it is saver to specify "" as the entry. I have dataannotations on so will see how to figure this out when i get there. Thanks for your help

Comment: I see what you are saying, but in this case, it's not exactly safer, since it does not work.

Comment: It works now since i have replaced the default for the GetDefaultValue for string to "" and not null.